# Unable to connect to the database postgres

Tags: postgresql

I have a job  on my k8s cluster that initializes a Postgres DB, but during the run, it can't connect to the db. I have deployed the same job in another cluster with a different RDS Postgres DB without having any issues.

Error:

```
Unable to connect to the database at "postgresql://<username>:<password>@<endpoint>:5432/boundary?sslmode=disable"
```

```
CREATE DATABASE "boundary"
    WITH ENCODING='UTF8'
    OWNER=<username>
    CONNECTION LIMIT=-1;
```

This is how my job is trying to establish the connection.

```
boundary database migrate -config /boundary/boundary-config.hcl || boundary database init  -config /boundary/boundary-config.hcl || sleep 10000
```

I can also connect to the db by myself, but the job can't do so. Since this job is able to run on other clusters, I'm trying to figure out what would be wrong with db. The db usernames has the same privileges as well. What do you think would cause such issues?

Thanks!

Comment: Is that the entire error message?  What if you use the same URI to connect using psql?

Comment: @jjanes Unfortunately, that's all I can see. I can connect to the db with the same URI. On [boundary doc](https://www.boundaryproject.io/docs/oss/installing/postgres), it says the username should have superuser role and this is an RDS cluster, there's no access to superuser. but the same configurations are working on another environment. It's quite odd :(